# What is the definition of "daily" for "how many scratch orgs you can create daily"?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

This [Scratch Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm) page talks about "how many scratch orgs you can create daily" and I just ran into this error:

> LIMIT_EXCEEDED: The signup request failed because this organization
>   has reached its active scratch org limit

at 1pm GMT after creating just a few scratch orgs.

Does anyone know what "daily" means here e.g. is it a rolling window or based on a particular timezone day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You apparently misread the error. You've actually reached your **active** limit, not the *daily* limit. You would need to delete at least one scratch org before creating another. They don't specify if the daily limit is reset at midnight or rolling, but in your case, it doesn't matter, you simply have too many active scratch orgs in your dev hub. It's ordinarily "impossible" to reach the daily limit, since the active limit is half the daily limit; you would need to delete all the orgs and create them again before you'd risk hitting the daily limit anyways.

Comment: Thanks! You are right I didn't read the message carefully enough. I just went into the dev hub and found 150 active orgs which is our active limit.

Comment: @KeithC You're welcome! Believe me, we've all misread an error at some point in our lives ☺.

Comment: On the daily limit, we are now running Jenkins multibranch pipelines that create scrratch orgs for our managed package builds. With branches and pull requests building, we may hit the daily limit at some point too.

Comment: @KeithC Well, maybe, but you'd still have to be deleting and recreating scratch orgs at double the active limit. It's pretty rare to be able to hit that limit, especially since a proper CI wouldn't recreate the org each time, just deploy changes. It's a lot easier to just redeploy changes every time. At least, that's how I'd do it.

Comment: Yeah we have talked about "recycling" orgs but creating/deleting from Jenkins seemed like the simplest approach. The dominant time taken in our builds remains the unit tests, and getting those to run in parallel on scratch orgs is proving difficult.

Comment: Just changed to `--durationdays 1` for Jenkins so if a build fails to do its `sfdx force:org:delete` then the orgs won't pile up.

Comment: I'd say it is very possible to hit the daily limit if you are running any kind of CI jobs. It is common to spin up an org, run tests, and then delete the org multiple times a day.

Comment: @JulianJoseph That's a bad CI/CD approach. That's like saying you're going to reinstall Android every time you build a new version of your Android app. Remember, there are real resources being consumed by the org creation process, which is why limits are in place, to remind you that Salesforce is a shared resource.

Comment: @sfdcfox I disagree that it is a bad approach, but I do agree that it is a resource-intensive approach. This is actually the approach we used at Salesforce on packages like NPSP by the most talented release engineering team I've worked with. Today you can look at commits and builds and see that orgs are being built each time: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/NPSP/commits/main

That being said, I'm very aware of those limits and Salesforce had much higher limits for itself. I think there is value in rebuilding each time but it doesn't work in every situation.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm very open to other approaches. I'd love to see another example of automated builds/tests running on scratch orgs that conserves resources. I think it would be challenging (but not impossible) to pass authentication between builds.

Comment: @JulianJoseph The better solution involves Scratch Org Pools. There's a nice article at [DX@Scale](https://docs.dxatscale.io/media-library/knowledge-articles/scratch-org-pooling-for-development) that talks about this. Most CI systems can handle this. Also, if you're talking about deployment steps, you can use Unlocked Packages hundreds of times a day for testing/validation.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for sharing this article. Pools definitely seem like an interesting way to cut down on setup time. In terms of using it for CI/CD builds, I'm concerned running automated tests against existing org builds may result in false positives/negatives since org data may be polluted by previous tests. I'll consider some other ways to address this.

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to know the answer to the question as asked, even though it wasn't the true issue, so I did a quick experiment.

For background, my Dev Hub is a standard Developer Edition for working on personal and open source Salesforce DX projects. It's far, far easier to hit limits in a Developer Edition, where the Daily Scratch Org limit is **6** and the Active Scratch Org limit is just **3**. In particular, running CI jobs that spawn and delete scratch orgs will devour the daily limit in, well, six pushes or fewer per day.

I recorded my limits as of 6 pm on 12/27:

```
$ sfdx force:limits:api:display -u david@ktema.org

NAME                                  REMAINING  MAXIMUM
────────────────────────────────────  ─────────  ─────────
ActiveScratchOrgs                     1          3
DailyScratchOrgs                      6          6
```

Then created and deleted a new scratch org, validating that `DailyScratchOrgs` ticks to 5 after the operation.

At 8 am the following day:

```
$ sfdx force:limits:api:display -u david@ktema.org
NAME                                  REMAINING  MAXIMUM
────────────────────────────────────  ─────────  ─────────
ActiveScratchOrgs                     1          3
DailyScratchOrgs                      5          6
```

so the limit does not reset at midnight EST.

At 7 pm the following day, 12/28, the limit has reset.

```
$ sfdx force:limits:api:display -u david@ktema.org
NAME                                  REMAINING  MAXIMUM
────────────────────────────────────  ─────────  ─────────
ActiveScratchOrgs                     1          3
DailyScratchOrgs                      6          6
```

So, daily scratch orgs is indeed a rolling 24 hour window. (Note that one active scratch org was created before and lived through this two-day observation period).

Comment: Thanks for this - helpful to know. One of my colleagues is aiming to get these numbers shown in a Jenkins build monitor as hitting the active limit is going to be a constant risk for us.

Comment: @KeithC, by any chance, did you get these shown? Would love to see how.

Comment: Hi @David Reed, is there a way to know at what time in the day the limit will be reset ?  Otherwise, is it possible to get (via SFDX) the datetime those last orgs were created ?

Comment: "Rolling" seems to be confirmed here by a Salesforce engineer: https://youtu.be/UQMn2rzJdjM?t=856